# R: Compare across IDs within the same data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5), c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b",
                                                         "a","a","a","b","b","b"),
                 c(300,295,295,25,25,25,25,25,20,20,20,300,295,295,300, 295,295), 
                 c("c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t"))
colnames(df) <- c("ID", "Group", "Price", "OtherNumber")

> df
   ID Group Price OtherNumber
1   1     a   300           c
2   1     a   295           d
3   1     a   295           e
4   2     b    25           f
5   2     b    25           g
6   2     b    25           h
7   2     b    25           i
8   3     b    25           j
9   3     b    20           l
10  3     b    20           m
11  3     b    20           n
12  4     a   300           o
13  4     a   295           p
14  4     a   295           q
15  5     b   300           r
16  5     b   295           s
17  5     b   295           t
```

I want to compare the first price of subsequent IDs. Only if the two subsequent IDs have the same initial price and are in the same group, I want to flag them. Just in case this was not very clear, here an example: I compare the first and second ID, but both the group (a vs. b) and the initial price is a mismatch (300 vs. 25). On the other hand, between ID 2 and 3, they are both in group b and have the same initial price of 25 (cf. row 4 and 8). The prices afterwards do not really matter as they may differ.

I figure, I must be able to work with the dplyr package and have determined a very rough solution (which does not yet work).

```
# Load dplyr
library(dplyr)

# Assign row numbers within IDs
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(subID = row_number())

# Isolate first observation in ID 
df2 <- df1[df1$subID == 1,]

# Set up loop to iterate through IDs
for (i in 2:length(df2)) {
  if (df2$Price[i] - df2$Price[i - 1] == 0) {
    df2$flag <- TRUE
  } else {
    df2$flag <- FALSE
  }
}
```

If you tell me that this is the only possible solution, I will obviously devote more resources to it, but I am sure there must be an easier solution. I checked on SO and maybe I missed something, but I was not able to find anything going into this direction. Thanks!

The output I want to get looks something like this:

```
   ID Group Price OtherNumber   flag
1   1     a   300           c  FALSE
2   1     a   295           d  FALSE
3   1     a   295           e  FALSE
4   2     b    25           f   TRUE
5   2     b    25           g   TRUE
6   2     b    25           h   TRUE
7   2     b    25           i   TRUE
8   3     b    25           j   TRUE
9   3     b    20           l   TRUE
10  3     b    20           m   TRUE
11  3     b    20           n   TRUE
12  4     a   300           o  FALSE
13  4     a   295           p  FALSE
14  4     a   295           q  FALSE
15  5     b   300           r  FALSE
16  5     b   295           s  FALSE
17  5     b   295           t  FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a data.table oneliner... cut into smaller pieces to view intermediate results; also see explanation at the bottom of the answer.

```
dt <- as.data.table( df )
dt[ dt[ , .SD[1], ID][ ( Group == shift( Group, type = "lead") & Price == shift( Price, type = "lead") ) |
                   ( Group == shift( Group, type = "lag") & Price == shift( Price, type = "lag),
                   flag := TRUE][is.na(flag), flag := FALSE], flag := i.flag, on = .(ID)][]

#     ID Group Price OtherNumber  flag
#  1:  1     a   300           c FALSE
#  2:  1     a   295           d FALSE
#  3:  1     a   295           e FALSE
#  4:  2     b    25           f  TRUE
#  5:  2     b    25           g  TRUE
#  6:  2     b    25           h  TRUE
#  7:  2     b    25           i  TRUE
#  8:  3     b    25           j  TRUE
#  9:  3     b    20           l  TRUE
# 10:  3     b    20           m  TRUE
# 11:  3     b    20           n  TRUE
# 12:  4     a   300           o FALSE
# 13:  4     a   295           p FALSE
# 14:  4     a   295           q FALSE
# 15:  5     b   300           r FALSE
# 16:  5     b   295           s FALSE
# 17:  5     b   295           t FALSE
```

explanation:
`dt[ , .SD[1], ID]` create a data.table with the first row of each `ID`

`[ Group == shift( ... , flag := TRUE]` sets the column `flag` to `TRUE` when the next (**or** previous) row has matching `Price` **and** `Group`.

`[is.na(flag), flag := FALSE]` fills in the rest (which is not TRUE) with `FALSE

`..flag := i.flag, on = .(ID)]` performs a left join (by reference, so it's fast and efficient) on the original data.table, to get the final result.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for (also thanks for the detailed explanation)! Just a quick remark: If I am not mistaken, in either of the two matching rows, it should be lag instead of lead.